# Create pseudo BGR image

Tags: spectrum

I have a hyperspectral image taken in the near infrared spectrum.
List of spectrum values:

```
[ 937.33  944.25  951.16  958.08  965.    971.92  978.85  985.77  992.7
  999.64 1006.57 1013.51 1020.45 1027.39 1034.33 1041.27 1048.21 1055.17
  1062.11 1069.07 1076.03 1082.98 1089.94 1096.91 1103.87 1110.84 1117.81
  1124.78 1131.76 1138.73 1145.7  1152.68 1159.68 1166.66 1173.65 1180.64
  1187.63 1194.62 1201.62 1208.62 1215.62 1222.62 1229.63 1236.64 1243.65
  1250.66 1257.67 1264.68 1271.7  1278.72 1285.75 1292.78 1299.81 1306.83
  1313.86 1320.9  1327.94 1334.98 1342.02 1349.06 1356.11 1363.16 1370.2
  1377.26 1384.32 1391.38 1398.43 1405.49 1412.55 1419.63 1426.69 1433.76
  1440.83 1447.91 1454.99 1462.07 1469.15 1476.23 1483.32 1490.41 1497.5
  1504.59 1511.68 1518.79 1525.89 1532.98 1540.09 1547.2  1554.31 1561.42
  1568.53 1575.65 1582.77 1589.89 1597.01 1604.14 1611.26 1618.39 1625.53
  1632.65 1639.79 1646.93 1654.08 1661.22 1668.35 1675.51 1682.65 1689.8
  1696.96 1704.12 1711.28 1718.44]
```

How do I create a pseudo BGR image?
Before that, I was working with data that was received in the visible range. And took the spectrum values corresponding to blue, green and red (470,530,640).
What spectra should I take here?
Thanks